# How to send sms to multiple recipient in GWT using java Using Twillio API

Tags: java, gwt, twilio

I am Using twilio API for sending sms. Using this API I can send SMS to one number but I want to know how to send one SMS to multiple recipient. I am sending one sms to one number is like this

```
smsParams.put("To", ToNumber); 
smsParams.put("From", fromNumber); 
smsParams.put("Body", Message); 
smsFactory.create(smsParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

At the moment, we require that you submit each outgoing SMS message as its own API request.

My suggestion would be looping through your recipients and making the requests. The API is [limited](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#example-1) to one message a second, but you can try to send more, and they will be queued up and delivered.

A workaround to this would be sending the messages asynchronously in case you need your client to return early.

Let me know if you have any questions about that.

Comment: Glad it answered your question @vijaychougule

Comment: Marcos I am sending sms in india now for per sms its charge is $0.01 so I want to purchase SMS Packs for Monthly basis how shall i purchase in Twilio   Any help? Thanks in adv

Comment: Hey @vijaychougule suggest contacting help@twilio.com asking this and they will be able to help you with that. Also, please make sure you mark the question as answered

Comment: Thanks marcos i will contact them help@twilio.com

Comment: if ten thousand messages are sent asynchronously, and there's only one DID, what's the maximum amount of time before they are all sent?  I ask because of questions relating to a maximum of one message per second (?).